# Android : Download file without .pfd, .png... at end of the link

Tags: android, pdf, browser, types, download

I try to download a file through the browser. it's working perfectly if a have that :

```
    String pdfUrl = "www.myLink.com/document/test.pdf";
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse(pdfUrl)); 
    startActivity(intent);
```

However if the link is :

```
    String pdfUrl = "www.myLink.com/document/test/";
```

It's very odd because it works on my browser "Chrome". I can download the 2 files....

Comment: Can you fin any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Using the URL without the full file name will not work, because the `Intent` system does not know the type of the resource behind the URI - it will probably launch a browser pointed to that address instead of a PDF viewer. What you could do, however, is explicitly specify the content type behind your URL by using `intent.setDataAndType()` instead of `intent.setData()`, like this:

```
String pdfUrl = "www.myLink.com/document/test/";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(pdfUrl), "application/pdf");

startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I'd also like to point out that "www.myLink.com/document/test.pdf" is not a valid URI - it lacks a schema. "http://www.myLink.com/document/test.pdf" on the other hand is.